# Fetching the data in dropdown list?

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, mysqli, fetch

My HTML code is here.how to fetch my this data from database?

```
<tr>    
   <td>City:
      <select name="city">
      <option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['city'];?>">Ahmedabad</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['city'];?>"> Vadodara</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['city'];?>"> Rajkot</option>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['city'];?>"> Surat</option>
      </select><br />
   </td>
```

Comment: This is very broad. Do you actually have a database already? If so, what are the fields/tables, etc? If not, come back when you have these!

Comment: please google for some tutorials regarding saving and fetching data from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming you have created the database and connected it,**

you can try something like this:

```
<?php

    $query = mysqli_query("YOUR QUERY HERE"); // Run your query

    echo '<select name="DROP DOWN NAME">'; // Open your drop down box

    // Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
       echo '<option value="'.$row['something'].'">'.$row['something'].'</option>';
    }

    echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box

  ?>
```

Here is the information about [mysqli_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) and [mysqli_fetch_array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp).

Comment: There's very little chance anyone would do a request for each of the options. It seems a lot more appropriate to do one request, and then output one `<option>` for each row of the results.

Comment: @jcaron OP only requested code for fetching the data.Why the downvote? the question itself is very broad.

Comment: I agree that the question is broad (and more to the point, the OP didn't make any effort to try to find the solution by himself), but in the context of a drop down menu, it is quite obvious that this is not the right answer.

Comment: @jcaron I agree but OP only asked for fetching data.

Comment: @jcaron now I edited the answer...Is this exactly you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is little old; however, sharing my answer for this will help in some ways whoever sees this post. 
Below answer worked for me which is inspired from the above verified answer with some corrections.

```
           <?php
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","your_db_username_here","your_db_password_here","your_db_name");
                $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT column_name FROM table_name");
                echo '<select name="NameHere">';
                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                         echo '<option>'.$row['column_name'].'</option>';
                     }
                echo '</select>';
            ?>
```